# properly comparing and finding difference between two structs with exported members using go-cmp

Tags: go, struct, go-cmp

I'm writing a Go application, and I want to create a test for it,
in that test, I query something from the db, insert it into a struct, and compare that struct values with a static struct of the same type that I had, if they match, the test succeeded, if not, I wanna show the difference. so I'm trying to use `go-cmp` package.

In general I'm getting this error:

```
panic: cannot handle unexported field at {main.fooTest}.F1.Int.neg:
    "math/big".Int
consider using a custom Comparer; if you control the implementation of type, you can also consider using an Exporter, AllowUnexported, or cmpopts.IgnoreUnexported [recovered]
```

I'm getting this is because of the `pgtype.Numeric` that I have in my struct

```
type fooTest struct {
    I1   int
    I2   *int
    S1   string
    S2   *string
    F1   pgtype.Numeric
    F2   *pgtype.Numeric
    Ff1  float64
    Ff2  *float64
    Ia1  []int
    Ia2  []*int
    Ia3  *[]int
    Sa1  []string
    Sa2  []*string
    Sa3  *[]string
    Fa1  pgtype.Float8Array
    Fa2  *pgtype.Float8Array
    Faf1 []float64
    Faf2 []*float64
    Faf3 *[]float64
}

so I tried to test with `AllowUnnexported` but the `cmp.Equal` line still fails with that error.

if !cmp.Equal(fooFoo, bar,cmp.AllowUnexported(fooTest{})) {
            t.Errorf("failed test: %v",cmp.Diff(fooFoo, bar))
        }
```

any ideas how to resolve this ?

Comment: also tried using https://github.com/r3labs/diff but it gives the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried

```
cmp.Equal(fooFoo, bar, cmp.AllowUnexported(pgtype.Numeric.Int{}))
```

The documentation of `AllowUnexported` doesn't mention that it recursively applies this to all values in the struct.

Comment: ahh now I understand how to use Allowunexported, this worked: cmp.AllowUnexported(big.Int{})

Comment: I didn't know what pgtype was, But it seems you figured it out.

Comment: Is there a way to Ignore all unexpected fields?